# How to wrap a hyperlink around each dynamically created ImageButton? Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am trying to create an image gallery for a website. I am using Visual Studio 2013 Premium and im trying to use the Colorbox jQuery lightbox plugin to display the images. I have got the plugin working in a simple web form. Now I am trying to get it working with my main code. It seems to work mainly by applying a class (in this case called "group1") to an anchor tag element. I have created a file upload control and have set it up to display the uploaded image file as image buttons in a panel on the page. When the page is loaded it displays any images (that are currently in the Data folder) in the panel. That's all working fine.

I want to be able to click on an image button and the Colorbox plugin will display it just like before (with my simple example where I applied a class to an anchor tag). However, it doesnt work. I think the reason is that I am applying the class to the ImageButton but not an anchor tag. I have tried the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

namespace imageGalleryTest
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            uploadImage();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                string filename = FileUpload1.FileName;
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Data/" + filename));
            }
            Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx");
        }

        private void uploadImage()
        {
            foreach (string strFileName in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Data/")))
            {
                ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(strFileName);
                imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/Data/" + fileInfo.Name;
                imageButton.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
                imageButton.Height = Unit.Pixel(100);
                imageButton.Style.Add("padding", "5px");
                imageButton.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(imageButton_Click);
                //imageButton.CssClass = "group1";
                Panel1.Controls.Add(imageButton);

            }
        }

        private void imageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect(((ImageButton)sender).ImageUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I click an image button it displays the image with a darkened background but does not apply any of the Colorbox effects to it.

I tried uncommenting this line but it didnt help:

```
//imageButton.CssClass = "group1";
```

I tried creating a hyperlink on the page and when an image button is clicked, assigned the image url of the image button to the navigate url of the hyperlink. Then when I click on the hyperlink it works fine and applies the Colorbox effect to the image.

```
private void imageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
       {
           HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = ((ImageButton)sender).ImageUrl;
       }
```

Then I tried to get it to direct automatically to the image url without having to click the hyperlink with this:

```
private void imageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
       {
           HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = ((ImageButton)sender).ImageUrl;
           Response.Redirect(HyperLink1.NavigateUrl);
       }
```

But it didnt work, it just displayed the image as before with a darkened background.

I feel if I could wrap an anchor tag around each image button as its created and apply the required class to that anchor tag then it might work but I dont know how.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got this working a different way as I wasnt having any luck with the above code. I abandoned the image button and instead created a hyperlink wrapped around an img tag in the code behind. So for each file in the folder it creates an image that has an anchor tag around it with the necessary class applied to it. This worked fine.

```
private void uploadImage()
        {
            string thumbnails = "<div id=\"photoThumbnailContainer\">";
            foreach (string strFileName in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Data/")))
            {            
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(strFileName);
                thumbnails += "<a href=\"Data/" + fileInfo.Name + "\" class=\"group1\"><div class=\"thumbnails\"><img src=\"Data/" + fileInfo.Name + "\" height=\"200px\" width=\"200px\" /></div></a>";   
            }
            thumbnails += "</div>";
            lblImageThumbnails.Text = thumbnails;
        }
```